# Knockout JS Mapping from JSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm receiving a JSON string and attempting to map it to a KOJS VM, but I don't see why the below code isn't working.

Here's my JS file:

```
var viewModel = {};

$.ajax({
  url: '../data/settings',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  }
});
```

The first alert displays:

```
{"remember":"false"}
```

My HTML, which isn't working is:

```
<span data-bind="value:remember"></span>
```

Do you know what might be going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK a KnockoutJS View Model is an object literal and therefore does not have a `length` property.

Comment: Oh, okay. That knowledge might make this debugging process go a bit smoother :) Thanks, @Kevin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be your binding code:

```
<span data-bind="value:remember"></span>
```

should be:

```
<span data-bind="text:remember"></span>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/Jj9DZ/

'value' is for form fields that have a value property (and may be abstracted to include `select` boxes as well)

Comment: Good catch, @Kevin. I had actually just caught this and made the change; still no dice, though.

Comment: Well, this works in the fiddle. But I had to omit your call to the mapping object, could be the issue is there.

Comment: Ah yeah, good point @Kevin. If I use the JSON.parse it works. But it seems to be having trouble mapping. Hrm!

Comment: In the end, I'm pretty sure this was my error. The mapping works if I use `fromJSON` and have this set correctly. Thanks @Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data might not be a JSON string so you want to use fromJS instead:

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

This question can help with debugging bindings: [How to debug template binding errors for KnockoutJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261296/any-good-techniques-to-debug-template-binding-faults-for-knockout-js)

Comment: Good suggestion. I had tried this as well, but when I do it it displays a length of `0`.

Comment: your viewModel.length will always be 0 since viewModel is a function.  this question can help with debugging bindings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261296/any-good-techniques-to-debug-template-binding-faults-for-knockout-js

Comment: +1 for the good link reference. You should put that in your answer