# Get element 'from Unable to parse bindings.' error in Knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

Sometimes I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: items is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: items()
```

I'm pretty satisfied with my current way of debugging binding faults - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242988/647845).

Problem is that I sometimes don't know what *element* to debug. I use the propertyname `items()` everywhere in my project for different contexts.

Right now the only thing I can do to find the element is searching through my whole project for `foreach: items()` and replace it for `debug: $data`.

Is there some way to find the *element* after a throw?

Is there a way to let Knockout.js throw the element's xpath during a binding fault?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a great way to do this to my knowledge, but you can make javascript work for you a bit more by using named function declarations.

so replace this:

```
foreach: items()
```

with something like this:

```
foreach: function shoppingcartItems(){ return items(); }
```

or instead (if you want context detail) put them within your context:

```
var someKOContext = {

   items: function someKOContextItems(){ return realItems() }

}

var someOtherKOContext = {

  items: function someOtherContextItems() { return realItems() }

}
```

These tricks should enhance the readability of the console error messages somewhat, and give you a bit more information to track down where your error is occurring (or at least which context to start with, or html element)