# Knockout observable visibility not working

Tags: knockout.js

**Intro**:

I have a simple requirement: Show or hide 1 of 2 divs depending on the value of an observable.

**What I have so far**:

Let's start with the html (very simple 2 divs - when 1 is visible the other one is hidden):

```
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView == 'aValue'">
html content....
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView != 'aValue'">
html content....
</div>
```

In my viewmodel I have the following:

```
self.ActiveClientSideView = ko.observable();
```

As well as after an Ajax call, the value gets updated:

```
successError: function (result) {
 if (result.Code == "INVALID_ADDRESS") {
 alert("invalid address"); 
 self.ActiveClientSideView = "AddressRecommendations";
                         }
```

The alert is in there to check if the code is firing, which it is.

What I would expect is the divs to show / hide as easily as updating the value of **ActiveClientSideView** what am I missing?

**EDIT (LATEST INFO):**

When the page initially loads, I can set the value of the observable in the init routine, and the visibility adjusts correctly, it is on subsequent (post page load events) , such as button clicks, or later on that the visibility does not dynamically adjust.

Comment: Have a look at the debug techniques here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261296/any-good-techniques-to-debug-template-binding-faults-for-knockout-js. In particular try outputting your model to a textbox and see what you get.

Comment: Seems like `ActiveClientSideView` isn't observable, which makes bindings unable to be in sync with its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ActiveClientSideView()` instead `ActiveClientSideView` in your `visible` binding:

```
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView() == 'aValue'">
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView() != 'aValue'">
```

**Update**

I've added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9mBS/6/) demo. All works correct.

You have bug in ajax call, also. You incorrect assign value to `ActiveClientSideView`.

Comment: I thought that was the case too, I'll update the question with my latest findings. But no, this isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ActiveClientSideView` is an `observable`, instead of:

```
self.ActiveClientSideView = "AddressRecommendations";
// no longer an observable and Knockout cannot notify subscribers
```

You should try:

```
self.ActiveClientSideView("AddressRecommendations"); 
// mutating the value using the observable function - notifying subscribers
```

Also (as pointed out by @Alexander as well), when checking the `observable` value, you should invoke the function first:

```
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView() == 'aValue'">
<div data-bind="visible: ActiveClientSideView() != 'aValue'">
```